# Clarification regarding rmvnorm in R

Tags: r, correlation

Apologies for my limited knowledge of Random Variables. I am working on a problem which requires me to generate a correlation matrix with the absolute  pairwise Pearson correlation should be close to 0.4 (off diagonal elements of the correlation matrix). To clarify further let me provide a concrete example. I am following the steps below:

```
Step 1: Get the sample correlation matrix between 5 products, 
call it sample_corr matrix (just to get the correlation sign +ve or -ve)


> sample_corr
       a          b          c          d          e
a  1.0000000 -0.1907169  1.0000000 -0.5872416  0.8346421
b -0.1907169  1.0000000 -0.1907169  0.6511824 -0.2783893
c  1.0000000 -0.1907169  1.0000000 -0.5872416  0.8346421
d -0.5872416  0.6511824 -0.5872416  1.0000000 -0.6638346
e  0.8346421 -0.2783893  0.8346421 -0.6638346  1.0000000
```

Now I need to discard the sample values and substitute them by number 0.4 (with maintaining the sign from the above sample matrix).

```
Step 2: replace values >0 and <0 with 0.4 and -0.4 respectively
sample_corr[sample_corr>0.0]<-0.4
sample_corr[sample_corr< 0]<-(-0.4)
diag(sample_corr)<-1
```

This replacement of the numbers is not a correct approach as it fails the positive-semi-definite test

```
> is.positive.semi.definite(sample_corr)
[1] FALSE
```

Now, despite that error,  I use this matrix to generate normal random numbers using rmvnorm with "svd" option (assuming standard deviation as 1)

```
gen_norm<-rmvnorm(5000,mean = rep(0,5),sigma=sample_corr,method = "svd")
```

The obtained correlation structure is as follows:

```
> cor(gen_norm)
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  1.0000000 -0.2068077 -0.3214124 -0.2837120 -0.3949594
[2,] -0.2068077  1.0000000 -0.2800788 -0.3087180  0.3548876
[3,] -0.3214124 -0.2800788  1.0000000 -0.2260995  0.4010528
[4,] -0.2837120 -0.3087180 -0.2260995  1.0000000 -0.3444349
[5,] -0.3949594  0.3548876  0.4010528 -0.3444349  1.0000000
```

Which is not very close to desired correlation but is acceptable to what I was looking for.

My questions are:
1. Why don't I get an error while I am using rmvnorm() to generate the random numbers ? 
2. How the correlation structure is corrected ?

Comment: All the eigen values of `sample_corr` are positive, so the matrix is positive definite. Can you show the code of `is.positive.semi.definite`?

Comment: I am using package matrixcalc, using its function is.positive.semi.definite

Comment: @javlacalle I have checked the eigen values as well. `Sample_corr` has negative eigen value. `> eigen(sample_corr, only.values = TRUE)
$values
[1]  2.0246211  1.4000000  1.4000000  0.3753789 -0.2000000`

Comment: Please check the values that you pasted. For safety, give the output of `dput(sample_corr)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to explain the behavior of the fix that `rmvnorm()` applies, you could instead try and repair the matrix yourself. Here's one way of doing so that appears to work better than the built-in repair within `rmvnorm()`, at least for this specific case (which is a pretty weird case if you ask me):

################### generate data #######################

```
# randomly generate a symmetric matrix
C1<-matrix(.8*(runif(25,0,1)>.5)-.4,5,5)
for(j in 1:5){
  for(n in j:5){
    C1[j,n]<-C1[n,j]
  }
}
diag(C1)<-1

# check to see if the random matrix is not positive semi-definite 
# so we can repair it (if its positive semi-definite, there's 
# nothing to repair)
eigen(C1)$values

##  e.g.
#    > eigen(C1)$values
#    [1]  1.9489125  1.4000000  1.4000000  0.6000000 -0.3489125
```

#################### repair the matrix ###################

```
# Perform a rank one update with the minimum distance necessary to make the matrix PSM
D<-eigen(C1)$values
V<-eigen(C1)$vectors
C2<- C1+V[,5]%*%t(V[,5])*(.Machine$double.eps-min(D[5],0))

# fix the diagonal
s<- diag(1/sqrt(diag(C2)))
C2<-s%*%C2%*%s
```

Sidenote: Check for yourself that if you apply this repair procedure on a matrix whose eigenvalues are all non-negative, C1 will equal C2.

######################### compare ########################

```
C1
C2

#    > C1
#               [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#    [1,]  1.0000000  0.4000000 -0.4000000 -0.4000000  0.4000000
#    [2,]  0.4000000  1.0000000  0.4000000  0.4000000 -0.4000000
#    [3,] -0.4000000  0.4000000  1.0000000 -0.4000000 -0.4000000
#    [4,] -0.4000000  0.4000000 -0.4000000  1.0000000  0.4000000
#    [5,]  0.4000000 -0.4000000 -0.4000000  0.4000000  1.0000000
#    
#    > C2
#               [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#    [1,]  1.0000000  0.2861488 -0.3186038 -0.2861488  0.3186038
#    [2,]  0.2861488  1.0000000  0.3186038  0.2861488 -0.3186038
#    [3,] -0.3186038  0.3186038  1.0000000 -0.3186038 -0.4240045
#    [4,] -0.2861488  0.2861488 -0.3186038  1.0000000  0.3186038
#    [5,]  0.3186038 -0.3186038 -0.4240045  0.3186038  1.0000000

# check to see if the procedure you did before will return similar 
# results with the repaired martix
cor(rmvnorm(5000,mean = rep(0,5),sigma=C2,method = "svd"))
#               [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
#    [1,]  1.0000000  0.2872494 -0.3294268 -0.2792972  0.3085973
#    [2,]  0.2872494  1.0000000  0.3042871  0.3004519 -0.3306211
#    [3,] -0.3294268  0.3042871  1.0000000 -0.3246630 -0.4447972
#    [4,] -0.2792972  0.3004519 -0.3246630  1.0000000  0.3149295
#    [5,]  0.3085973 -0.3306211 -0.4447972  0.3149295  1.0000000
```

Comment: This follows the procedure outlined by John D'Errico, certified MATLAB wizard:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/6057-repair-non-positive-definite-correlation-matrix

Answer (score 0):

I thought this is worth sharing to people looking for similar solution as I.  I found a function called Nearest Positive Definite Matrix `nearPD` in the `Matrix`package of `R`. It is what I was looking for in addition to Emily's solution. Here is an excellent [blog](https://nickhigham.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/the-nearest-correlation-matrix/) I found by Nick Higham which explains the function. Lastly, here is the [link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html) for the function discreption.

Answer (score 0):

(mvtnorm version 1.1-0)

As of today (April 2020), The function `rmvnorm` with `method = "svd"` amounts to

```
    s. <- svd(sigma)
    if (!all(s.$d >= -sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) * abs(s.$d[1]))) {
        warning("sigma is numerically not positive semidefinite")
    }
    R <- t(s.$v %*% (t(s.$u) * sqrt(pmax(s.$d, 0))))

    retval <- matrix(rnorm(n * ncol(sigma)), nrow = n, byrow = !pre0.9_9994) %*% R
    retval <- sweep(retval, 2, mean, "+")
    colnames(retval) <- names(mean)
    retval
```

So basically, if I am not mistaken, this means that all negative eigenvalues of `sigma` are set to zero when its matrix square root (denoted `R`) is computed.